# Bitmap Collision vs SVG vs Box2D? What should I use?

Tags: javascript, bitmap, svg, box2d

I am trying to make a worms or tanks like game in Javascript that I want to be crossbrowser, crossplatform.

In the game when the player shoots the ground it creates a crater, now to detect collision should I use Bitmap Collision aka pixel perfect collision, or SVG, or should I use Box2D (all geometry), or a combination of Box2d with pixelperfect...

what do you recommend? Can you point me in any direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

box2djs http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/ is the best I've found and I've looked at plenty. It isn't well documented and doesn't even seem to be a very active project anymore, but readability of code, browser portability and performance all go in favor of box2js in my opinion. I've seen others recommend http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/ but I didn't like it at all and I couldn't get it to work in ie8. I've extended some of the examples for box2djs at a hobby site where I'm using it [JellyRobotics](http://www.jellyrobotics.com/2012/01/13/js-code-battle/). Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately box2d only does non-convex low count polygons.

Comment: That's the trade for browser portability. Otherwise you're heading into the need for graphic acceleration to handle a large number of verticies.

Comment: What part of box2dweb is it you don't like? How does it differ from box2djs? I recently started working with the former and haven't looked at the latter; that's why I'm curious. Is the syntax different? Is the source more hard to follow? Worse performance? I've got to admit that the box2dweb source is in many ways ineffective but not too hard to follow. For documentation I found the Flash/AS3 box2d manual and documentation to be very helpful.

Comment: I didn't like the source for sure. Not as easy to figure out. Since documentation is pretty much nil for both that was important to me. Also, I never got box2dweb to work in iE8. Since I already was leaning toward box2djs I probably didn't try for very long however :)